# Transforming Elliptic Curve to Hessian Form

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography

In the [The Hessian Form of an Elliptic Curve, (NP Smart - ‎2001)](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-44709-1_11.pdf), they began with the elliptic curve

$$E': y^2 +xy = x^3 + x^2 + b$$ defined over the $\operatorname{GF}(2^{192})$ with the polynomial basis in $t$ over $\operatorname{GF}(2)$, where $$t^{191} + t^9 + 1 = 0.$$
with

$$b =  \texttt{0x4DE3965E00F2A1C6C9750156A6FEFBE5EEF780BF3EF20E48}$$

The curve group order

$$ 6 \cdot q = 3138550867693340381917894711648254768837315541933943803842$$ with prime $q$. A point of order 3 on $E'$ is given by the point $(x_3,y_3)$;

$$x_3 = \texttt{0x4763CFBC4340674B749E57887850E92C9B6BEDF58EEDC3BF}$$
$$y_3 = \texttt{0x14A96A1E53DCC3E73CFB22B80E8658CE0D6D8E82ED2AEC7D}$$

Then proposed a change of variable

$$ X = x + x_3 \quad Y =y+sx+x^2$$ where $$s = \frac{x_3^2+y_3}{x_3},$$

then the elliptic form is obtained.

$$E:Y^2 + XY + x_3 Y = X^3$$

Then using the above the Hessian Form is obtained;

$$ x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = Dxyz$$ where

$$D = \texttt{ 0x16A4C7C2030FAD1380ABF8C2D47DC3E0C20AF62F6EDD06A7}$$

1. How does one find a point with order 3?
2. What is the intuition behind the change of variables?
3. How the Hessian form is obtained in the last step?

Comment: If you have a group of order $6q$ where $3\nmid q$, and pick any point on it at random and multiply it by $2q$, there is a two-thirds chance that the result is a point of order $3$.

Comment: So the other possibility is the identity?

Comment: Indeed, so that's a cue to try again. I should point out that this is a very standard trick in computational number theory.

Comment: @AnginaSeng to verify this, I've coded a SageMath . $order_1  =  334$ and $order_3  =  666$ over 1000 random sample, [link](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=oergqh). What is the theory of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the situation in the OP is related to a special example, i will use this example to illustrate the steps. Computations are done in sage. Some ingredients in the OP differ from the one in the reference [Smart N.P., The Hessian form of an Elliptic Curve], these are marked in red. (Colors are also used to mark matching pieces in longer computations.) All computational details are given, if the computer support feels annoying for a community reader, please skip it, the remained part is still giving the frame of the structure.

We consider the field
$$
F=\Bbb F_q=\Bbb F_2[T]/(T^{\color{red}{191}}+T^9+1)
$$
with $q=2^{191}$ elements (migrated letter for the usual reason). Let $t$ be $T$ modulo the quotient ideal.

We associate the curve $E'$, given by the affine equation:
$$
E': \ y^2 +xy = x^3 + x^2 + b\ .
$$
The order of the curve is $6N$, with a big prime $N$. Let us initialize the curve in sage, and check the order.

```
R.<T> = PolynomialRing(GF(2))
F.<t> = GF(2^191, modulus=T^191 + T^9 + 1)

b = F.fetch_int(0x4DE3965E00F2A1C6C9750156A6FEFBE5EEF780BF3EF20E48)
x3 = F.fetch_int(0x4763CFBC4340674B749E57887850E92C9B6BEDF58EEDC3BF)
y3 = F.fetch_int(0x14A96A1E53DCC3E73CFB22B80E8658CE0D6D8E82ED2AEC7D)

E = EllipticCurve(F, [1, 1, 0, 0, b])
N = ZZ(3138550867693340381917894711648254768837315541933943803842 / 6)

Q = E( (x3, y3) )    # this is the given point. Is it a 3-torsion point?
print("For the given point Q do we have 3.Q = O? {}\n"
      .format(3*Q == E(0)))

# we check that multiplication with 6N maps a random point P to O.
P = E.random_point()
print("For some random point P, do we have 6N.P = O? {}\n"
      .format(6*N*P == E(0)))
```

We obtain so far:

```
For the given point Q do we have 3.Q = O? False

For some random point P, do we have 6N.P = O? True
```

---

So $Q$ is not a $3$-torsion point, it is rather a point of (prime) order $N$, useful for the usual cryptographic reasons.

```
sage: N*Q
(0 : 1 : 0)
sage: N * Q == E(0)
True
```

We will forget this point $Q$ in the following, thus also using the notations / the variables `x3` and `y3` for other purposes.

---

In order to construct a $3$-torsion point, we consider the $3$-torsion (or division) polynomial, which is
$$
x^4+x^3+b\ .
$$
Formally one can see this as follows. Let $(x{_0},y{_0})$ be a point on the curve. The formal differential of the given curve equation, computed in this point, is $2y_0\; dy+x_0\; dy+y_0\; dx+3x_0^2\; dx+2x_0^2\; dx=0$, i.e. $(x_0^2+y_0)\; dx +x_0\; dy=0$. We formally replace $dx$, $dy$ by $(x-x_0)$, $(y-y_0)$ getting the tangent/line equation $(x_0^2+y_0)(x-x_0)+x_0(y-y_0)=0$. Its **s**lope is a function $s$ of/in $(x_0,y_0)$, formally obtained as
$$s=s(x_0,y_0)=\frac1{x_0}(x_0^2+y_0)\ .$$
Now we would like to obtain an equation for the first component in the identity $-2T_3=T_3$ of a $3$-torsion point $T_3$. It is $s^2+s+1=x$. This leads to $x^4+x^3+b=0$.

---

Code computing this polynomial and using it:

```
pol = E.division_polynomial(3)
# or pol = E.torsion_polynomial(3)

roots = pol.roots(ring=F, multiplicities=False) 
print(f"The given polynomial has {len(roots)} roots over F")

# and we try to lift the roots one by one
three_torsion_points = []

print("\n...lifting found roots...")
for r in roots:
    try:
        U = E.lift_x(r)
        three_torsion_points.extend([U, -U])
        print(f"... OK: LIFTED ROOT {hex(r.integer_representation())}")

    except:
        print(f"... could *NOT* lift the root {hex(r.integer_representation())}")

print()
for U in three_torsion_points:
    Ux, Uy = U.xy()
    hexu = hex(Ux.integer_representation())
    hexv = hex(Uy.integer_representation())
    print(f"Computed 3-torsion point with components:\nx3 = {hexu}\ny3 = {hexv}")
```

This gives:

```
The given polynomial has 2 roots over F
...lifting found roots...
... OK: LIFTED ROOT 0x665dde483ee9b618357325c85666c1f9241d19d45e76d8e3
... could *NOT* lift the root 0x66b8ff1e96ee97559108d9e34fd7c48a372313924b5e81ea

Computed 3-torsion point (u, v) with:
u = 0x665dde483ee9b618357325c85666c1f9241d19d45e76d8e3
v = 0x38a4365e3388fc1094ba6755e471788805c9961f52054d79
Computed 3-torsion point (u, v) with:
u = 0x665dde483ee9b618357325c85666c1f9241d19d45e76d8e3
v = 0x5ef9e8160d614a08a1c9429db217b97121d48fcb0c73959a
```

To find all points of order three, we asked for the corresponding division polynomial, then for its roots in $F$, which correspond to the $x$-components of the $3$-torsion points. Then we tried to lift. Lifting needs the existence of a square root for the remained equation in $y$ (from $E'$),  after plugging in the found $x$ value. We could lift one root of the $3$-torsion polynomial.

So the given point $Q$ is not a $3$-torsion point. But we have a good one.
(There are two points sharing the same $x$-component, denoted above by `u`.)

Let us check that `pol` is in fact $x^4+x^3+b$:

```
sage: S = pol.parent()
sage: x, = S.gens()
sage: pol == x^4 + x^3 + b
True
```

This concludes (1).

---

Let $T_3(x_3,y_3)$ be the first $3$-torsion point from above. (The other one is $-T_3$.)

The second question. We are using a transformation of coordinates, which maps $T_3$ to the point $(0,0)$ of an other elliptic curve with equation in $X,Y$, obtained by passing from $(x,y)$ to $(X,Y)$ via
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x &= X-x_3=X+x_3\ ,\\
y &= Y-sx-x^2_{\color{red}3}=Y+sx+x^2_{\color{red}3}\ ,
\end{aligned}
\right.
\\
&\qquad
\qquad \text{ with }t=\frac{y_3}{x_3}\ ,\ s=x_3+t=x_3+\frac{y_3}{x_3}
\\
&\left\{
\begin{aligned}
X &= x+x_3\ ,\\
Y &=y+sx+x^2_{\color{red}3}\ ,
\end{aligned}
\right.
\\
&\qquad
\qquad \text{ so that }T_3(x_3,y_3)
\\
&\qquad
\qquad \text{ goes to }
(X_3,Y_3)=(x_3+x_3,y_3+sx_3+x_3^2)=(0,0)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
We plug in $(x,y)$ from above in the equation $y^2 +xy = x^3 + x^2 + b$ of the given curve $E'$ and obtain (recalling that in our case $2=0$, so that for instance squaring is compatible with addition) an equation in $(X,Y)$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
y^2 &= (Y-sx-x^2_3)^2=(Y+sx+x^2_3)^2=Y^2+s^2x^2+x^4_3\\
&=Y^2+(x_3^2+t^2)(X^2+x_3^2) + x_3^4\ ,\\
&=Y^2+x_3^2X^2+t^2X^2+y_3^2\ ,\\
&=Y^2+s^2X^2+y_3^2\ ,
\\[2mm]
xy &=(X+x_3)(Y+s(X+x_3)+x^2_3)\\
&=XY+x_3Y + (x_3+t)(X^2+x_3^2)+x_3^2X +x_3^3\ ,\\
&=XY+x_3Y + x_3X^2+tX^2+x_3^3+x_3y_3  +x_3^2X +x_3^3\\
&=XY+x_3Y + x_3X^2+tX^2+x_3y_3  +x_3^2X \ ,
\\[2mm]
x^3+x^2+b
&=(X^3+x_3X^2+x_3^2X+x_3^3)+(X^2+x_3^2)+b\ ,\\[2mm]
&\text{ which implies}\\[2mm]
0 &=(y^2+xy)\pm(x^3+x^2+b)\\
&=Y^2 + \color{red}{s^2X^2} +\color{blue}{y_3^2}\\
&\qquad + XY + x_3Y + \color{red}{sX^2} + \color{blue}{x_3y_3}  +x_3^2X \\
&\qquad\qquad
 + (X^3 + \color{red}{x_3X^2} + x_3^2X + \color{blue}{x_3^3})
 + (\color{red}{X^2} + \color{blue}{x_3^2})+\color{blue}{b}
\\
&=Y^2 + XY + x_3Y+X^3\\
&\qquad+ \color{red}{\underbrace{(s^2+s+x_3+1)}_{=0}}X^2 + \color{blue}{0}
\\
&=Y^2 + XY + x_3Y+X^3\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Note that the red term $s^2+s+x_3+1$ vanishes, since
$x_3$ is a root of the  $3$--torsion polynomial $x^4+x^3+b$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
x_3^2(s^2+s+x_3+1)
&=x_3^2\left(
x_3^2+\frac{y_3^2}{x_3^2} +
x_3+\frac{y_3}{x_3} +
x_3+1
\right)
\\
&=x_3^4+\color{blue}{y_3^2+x_3y_3}+x_3^2\\
&=x_3^4+\color{blue}{x_3^3+x_3^2+b}+x_3^2\\
&=x_3^4+\color{blue}{x_3^3+b}\\
&=0\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The sage code checking this vanishing is:

```
for U in three_torsion_points:
    x3, y3 = U.xy()
    s = x3 + y3/x3
    if s^2 + s + x3 + 1 != 0:
        continue
    hexu = hex(x3.integer_representation())
    hexv = hex(y3.integer_representation())
    print(f"ss + s + x3 + 1 = 0 for the values:\nx3 = {hexu}\ny3 = {hexv}")
```

It gives:

```
ss + s + x3 + 1 = 0 for the values:
x3 = 0x665dde483ee9b618357325c85666c1f9241d19d45e76d8e3
y3 = 0x38a4365e3388fc1094ba6755e471788805c9961f52054d79
ss + s + x3 + 1 = 0 for the values:
x3 = 0x665dde483ee9b618357325c85666c1f9241d19d45e76d8e3
y3 = 0x5ef9e8160d614a08a1c9429db217b97121d48fcb0c73959a
```

Note that the procedure of moving the torsion point $T_3(x_3,y_3)$ to the point $(0,0)$ of an other elliptic curve in long Weierstraß form in $X,Y$, while also moving the tangent in $(0,0)$ to $Y=0$ is a standard procedure. See e.g.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_form_of_an_elliptic_curve#Definition

in the proposition [ *Conversely...* ].
This answers the second question (structurally and programmatically).

---

To obtain the hessian form from the equation:
$$
E''\ :\ Y^2 + XY + x_3Y = X^3\ ,
$$
we proceed as in *loc. cit.*, page 120, [§3. The Hessian Form of an Elliptic Curve]. The values for $a_1$, $a_3$ are in our case explicitly $1$ and $x_3$, so for instance $\Delta =x_3^3(1-27x_3)=x_3^3(1+x_3)=b$, and $\delta = 1+x_3$. We compute a root of the polynomial in $T$
$$
T^3-\delta T^2+\frac 13 \delta^2T+x_3\delta^2
$$
and build
$$
D=3\frac{\mu-\delta}\mu
 =1+\frac{\delta}\mu
\ .
$$
The hex value for this number is...

```
PF.<T> = PolynomialRing(F)
delta = x3 + 1
mu = (T^3 - delta*T^2 + delta^2*T + x3*delta^2).roots(multiplicities=False)[0]
D = 1 + delta/mu
print(f"D is {hex(D.integer_representation())}")
```

which gives:

```
D is 0x16a4c7c2030fad1380abf8c2d47dc3e0c20af62f6edd06a7
```

which is the same value as in *loc. cit.*.

Comment: Might be interested in [What information is revealed if we send our points in Projective Coordinates?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/83652/18298)?